# Splitting up Step Definitions

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber

Currently I have one java class (Step Definitions.java) that contains all -

```
@Before, @After, @Given, @When, @Then
```

I want to split these annotations into three different classes. One class for the @Before / @After. One class for @Given; One class for @When; and One class for @Then.

All 4 classes will be under the same package. Can this be done? Do I have to change anything in the runner class? Any other references I have to make to these seperate classes? or should this just work like that, when I call the Gherkin in my feature file?!

Answer (score 1):

It will work out off the box. As long as the code is mentioned in the package structure given to the glue option for cucumberoptions, it will be loaded and executed. All the stepdefinition and hook code are loaded for each scenario, so doesnt matter which class the code exists.

Though better would be to separate them according to parts of the application they deal with.

Comment: I don't have a glue option since my Step Definitions exist in the same package as the Runner Class. So all I have to do is split the hooks into their own classes in the same package and it should work?? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Note that Cucumber does not distinquish between steps starting with Given/When/Then; i.e. there is no technical difference between "Given I split my steps" or "When I split my steps". So splitting them according to keyword (Given/When/..) doesn't really make sense. Like @Grasshopper said; it would make more sense to split the steps according to the part of your domain they deal with (i.e. steps to do with Customers, steps to do with Accounts, etc)